# Redirect everything but .well-known in NGINX (Let's Encrypt)

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I want to get a certificate via the [`letsencrypt.sh`](https://github.com/lukas2511/letsencrypt.sh.git) so I have to provide a challenge on HTTP.

Already I use NGINX to forward to SSL (served on a `nodejs` server). Now I want to still redirect everything to SSL, but not the challenge.

Here is my config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    server_name screen.example.com;

    location /.well-known { }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Opening a challenge URL still redirects me to HTTPS.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmm, when I use an empty `return` I can't start nginx.  `nginx -t` fails with: `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "return" directive in /etc/nginx/...`.  I'm using `nginx` 1.4.6.  What version are you running?

Comment: @mgalgs you have to remove the empty return statement, look at the edited config snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh my, the config seems to work. I just requested the wrong path.

The `letsencrypt.sh`'s default is `.acme-challenges` - I changed this to

`WELLKNOWN="/usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge"` in `config.sh`