# Let's Encrypt using webroot on nginx with an SSL redirect

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I have a web site being served with `nginx` with the following requirements:

1. Redirect all http -> https
2. Zero-downtime Let's Encrypt certificate renewal

In order to satisfy (1) I have a small http->https redirect in my `nginx` config.  In order to satisfy (2) I'll need to modify said config so that I can use the webroot Let's Encrypt authentication method.

I'm trying to figure out the optimal solution that will satisfy both requirements.  I've come up with the following, which works.

Before:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

After:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location ~ /\.well-known\/acme-challenge {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        allow all;
    }
    if ($request_uri !~ /\.well-known) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

However, I was hoping to figure out another way of doing it.  The reasons for that are:

1. [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).  Might not be such a big deal in this case because this is just the http->https redirect, which should be *very* low-traffic.
2. More importantly, avoiding the `if` would make it easier to bolt on webroot authentication to all of my sites running behind `nginx` since I could just plop that `location` directive in a `.conf` that I could then include willy-nilly inside all of my little http->https redirect blocks.

In [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/752358/redirect-everything-but-well-known-in-nginx-lets-encrypt), Alex gives an example using a bare `return` statement, but that doesn't work for me (`nginx -t` complains with `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "return" directive in /etc/nginx/...`).

Is there a better way of doing this?  Or is my solution above as good as it gets?

Comment: I'n not sure zero downtime with 100% uptime possible, but you can probably get close. Can you clarify your requirements? My Let's Encrypt certificates seem to renew, and I redirect everything from http to https, and I serve the acme-challenge directory over https. Maybe I'm wrong but it seems ok... have you actually tried this and had a failure? There's a LE forum thread that may be interesting here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/could-not-connect-to-http-domain-name-org-well-known-acme-challenge-xxxx/15748/3

Comment: I don't mean zero downtime _ever_, I just mean zero downtime while renewing my certs (which I plan on doing in a nightly cron job).  I have users on my site 24x7 so even a few seconds in the middle of the night is not ideal.

I hadn't even thought about renewing over https!  Problem is that I have a www -> non-www redirect on https too, so either way I'll have to use this `if`...  So I'm thinking that (unless there's a better way to do it without the `if`) I'll just go with what I have in my Q.

Comment: Ah there's one more problem with doing it over https, the webroot plugin [doesn't actually support the `tls-sni-01` challenge type](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#plugins).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the `if` with a normal location:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        allow all;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Reason: the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered.

> To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks
>   locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among
>   them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and
>   remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of
>   their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular
>   expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding
>   configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found
>   then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is
>   used.

Source: [Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: @Tim quoted in his comment a LE-forum thread which does solve the problem similar, but uses `rewrite` instead of `return`. this is not adviced by nginx devs as rewrites are generally costly performance wise.

Comment: Yes, it's not quite as good that way. However the regular expression match above can probably be removed, as I think Nginx evaluates rules from most to least specific. Might reduce CPU usage very slightly.

Comment: you are right. The quoted part states it .. just didn't notice it applies here as well: the longest prefix location will be used. I will edit the answer. Thanks @Tim

Comment: another thought I had just now: which would be used? a `return` within the `server {}` or the `location /.well-known/acme-challenge` ? perhaps `location /` is not necessary at all?

Comment: "location /" with the 301 return is required for the https redirect.

Comment: yeah. I tried it. A `return` on the same level as the `location` would always be preferred.

Comment: imho, this config could be modified to a more general approach with removing `server_name` and replacing the domain within the `return` with `$host`. optionally the `root` could make use of the `$host` variable as well. this would result in a "dynamic" delivery of the appropriate challenge when using multiple ssl server blocks.